Given an URL that opens an iOS app, how do I make that into a functional icon on the iOS home screen?
Like many former Mint users who had to transition to Credit Karma, I am frustrated by how many steps it takes to get to the data I want to see. Recently Credit Karma sent me a promotional e-mail with a button that took me directly to the Transactions page in the app. I would like to make an icon on my iOS home screen that does the same.
I extracted the URL from the e-mail. It is:
https://www.creditkarma.com/u/networth/transactions
When I click on this in iOS, it takes me directly to the Transactions page in the app, as I hoped [1].
To create an iOS home screen icon for a website, you need to open the website in Safari, but the first challenge was that when I opened the above URL in Safari, it redirected to the Intuit login page instead and that page did not seem to have the ability to open the app.
I found that if I turned on Airplane mode [2], I could open the link in Safari (it would not load, obviously, but neither would it redirect). When I created a Home Screen icon from that, it almost works: it takes me to an Intuit login page with the following banner offering to open the app:

When I click "Open" I am taken to the Transactions page, which is what I want, but is not the same one-click behavior I got from the original link.
So my question is, can anyone suggest a way to get this to work in one click?
Footnotes:
[1] Clarification: it may take me to the login page the first time, but once I click the "Open" then subsequent clicks will take me directly to the app. The icon, however, always requires the extra step of visiting the login page.
[2] The following question seems to suggest the same workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883736/how-to-have-a-custom-url-for-an-icon-on-the-ios-home-screen. They also suggest an "iPhone Configuration Utility", but I can't find a link to that anywhere!

It‘s called „Apple Configurator“ nowadays.

The shortcuts app lets you launch apps and assign them a different icon, as you are assigning an icon to the shortcut. You don't need a URL, it's all built into  iOS. I've used it to distinguish some apps with similar icons, works a treat!
